# Trying to to show error message but having problems with for->if->else

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I'm having problem i'd like to show some kind of error message ("name not found etc") if i cant find name matching the input name. The proplem is when i try to solve this with if else, the for loop loops 20 times the error message. What is the best way to make this work? Without the error message it works fine.
This is the html file:

```
<h3>What is the name you want to look up?</h3>
<h4>And remember to use capital letter</h4>

<input 
    type="text"
    #nameParam
    placeholder="for example Ville"
    ng-pattern
    >

<button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    (click)="nameParam"
    type="submit">Search
</button>

<div *ngFor="let x of nameArray">
    <div *ngIf="x.name === nameParam.value; else elseBlock">
        <td>{{"There are " + x.amount + " " + "people named " + x.name + " working at Solita!" }}</td>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Could not find the name</ng-template>
```

And this is the ts file. Note that i have commented code out because i didint get it to work.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import nameData from '../../names/names.json'



interface INames {
        name: string,
        amount: number
}

const { names } = nameData

@Component({
    selector: 'app-four',
    templateUrl: './four.html',
    styleUrls: ["./four.css"]
})


export class FourComponent {

    nameArray: Array<INames> = names

    constructor() { 
       // console.log(this.nameArray)
    }
    // getNameAndAmount(nameParam: any) {
    //     for(let x of this.nameArray) {
    //         if(x.name == nameParam.value) {
    //             console.log(nameParam.value)
    //             return nameParam.value
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these lines in your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let x of nameArray">
    <div *ngIf="x.name === nameParam.value; else elseBlock">
        <td>{{"There are " + x.amount + " " + "people named " + x.name + " working at Solita!" }}</td>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Could not find the name</ng-template>
```

to this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasName(nameParam.value); else elseBlock">
     <div *ngFor="let x of nameArray">
            <td *ngIf="x.name === nameParam.value">{{"There are " + x.amount + " " + "people named " + x.name + " working at Solita!" }}</td>
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Could not find the name</ng-template>
```

In your ts file create a public method.

```
public hasName(name: string) {
   // this line will depend on your model , this assumes that IName has name attribute 
   return this.nameArray.some(elem => elem.name === name);
}
```

Comment: That helps but there is still the problem that it now show the error message before you have typed anything. But thanks tho!

Comment: Also the console log inside the function gets called twice as soon as i open the component in browser